# Voice Leading in Göncz’s completion of Contrapunctus 14

Tags: harmony, analysis, counterpoint

[image]

My question relates to the attached extract from Zoltan Göncz’s completion of Bach’s Contrapunctus 14 from The Art of Fugue, and specifically the chord marked with the arrow.

To my mind, it appears to be a G minor harmony with a seventh in the bass, the bass note being approached by leap. Would you consider the treatment of the F in the bass to be within the parameters of acceptable voice leading in a Bachian style?

Comment: I seem to be missing something. The bass looks entirely stepwise to me.

Comment: @Aaron - Thirds count as leaps (at least that's what I was taught), and the D-F interval in the bass is a third.

Comment: @Dekkadeci Ah, I see my mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the chord vertically in isolation, it does appear to be a G minor seventh chord; however, it's actually a Bb major chord, with the G acting as a  suspension (retrogression) from the preceding G minor chord (on beat 2).

Here's a broader analysis of the passage, in G for ease of notation:

[image: RNA of OP passage]

The overall architecture is

- (m. 1) tonic
- (m. 2) dominant
- (m. 3) tonic
- (m. 4) predominant
- (m. 5) dominant
- (m. 6) tonic (rather, G7 as secondary dominant)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I think I agree with you that the F in the bass is the 7th of a 3rd inversion G minor. The fact that the F resolves to E, the 3rd of the C dominant 7th at the beginning of measure 4, as would be expected in classical harmony, tends to confirm that idea.
I's be interested to hear what your overall harmonic analysis is. There are so many hold-over notes and suspensions, the "true" harmony often isn't revealed until the notes resolve, and the key centers seems to be constant shifting to new areas.

Edit: I agree with Aaron's analysis. I didn't see the post until I submitted my comment.